# UiImagePickerController - more than one photo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Iphone app, IOS 5 and up.

There are similar questions to this one on SO but I haven't encountered this exact scenario so I'll ask. I'm editing an existing app that allows lets you take a photo which it resizes and sends to a web service.

I need to add the ability to take 3 photos, resize each and send to the same service. I thought it would be just a matter of repeating what was already in the app but it uses the UIImagePickerController which apparently only allows one photo per use.

So the way it works is that there's a 'Take Photo' button which calls the method below. Once that photo is taken another button appears that says 'Take another photo' (I added this button) and I have it calling the same method but it is just copying over the previous photo, which is to be expected really. How should I best alter this to accommodate 3 photos?

This is the takephoto method that I'm calling.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured out how to do this. I added a tag to the button calling the method, through IB.

Then in the takephoto method I assigned the imagePickerController a tag based on the tag of the button that tapped. Like this:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

   if([sender tag] == 2)
   {
       imagePickerController.view.tag = 2;
   }
   //And so on...

   imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   imagePickerController.delegate = self;
   [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];   
}
```

Then in the ImagePickerController didFinishedPickingMediaWithInfo method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

  if(picker.view.tag == 2)
  {
     //Do stuff here
  }
}
```

So, I'll probably have to create three different buttons for each of the three possible photos, I'm sure there's a better way than that but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/photopicker/Introduction/Intro.html
, check the take photo part of this demo project.